# Is continuous and integrable function bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have a function $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ continuous and integrable on $\mathbb R$. Is $f$ bounded?

Comment: No. e.g. $\exp$ is integrable, continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, and no bounds.

Comment: @servabat I think that the OP means by integrable that $\int_{-\infty}^{+ \infty} f $ is finite.

Comment: It's bounded almost everywhere.

Comment: Could anyone provided references or idea of the proof, that integrable and continuous $f$ is bounded a.e.?

Comment: As my answer below shows, it is *not* necessarily bounded a.e. (that is, there is no $E$ of zero measure and $c>0$ s.t. $x\notin E$ implies $|f(x)|<c$). Btw, for continuous functions, there is no difference between "bounded" and "bounded a.e.".

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/482934/9464

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, not even if you require the integral to be finite. Consider a function that is zero except on $[n,n+\frac{1}{n^3}]$ where it is a piecewise linear function connecting $(n,0)$, $(n+\frac{1}{2n^3}, n)$ and $(n+\frac{1}{n^3}, 0)$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and comment.

Answer (score 1):

No! See this example here [If $f\in L^1(\Bbb R,dx)$ then prove that for almost every $x\in\Bbb R$ $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} f(nx) = 0.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2527941/if-f-in-l1-bbb-r-dx-then-prove-that-for-almost-every-x-in-bbb-r-lim-lim)
Where the function is a Polynomial on each interval $[n, n+\frac{1}{2^n}]$ and zero elsewhere.

Consider $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$
\begin{align*}
f(x)= \begin{cases}
2^{n/2}P_n(x)& \text{if} ~~ n\le x\le n+\frac{1}{2^n} ~~\text{$n\in\mathbb{N}$}\\
0 &\text{ if}~~~j+\frac{1}{2^j}\le x\le j+1~~\text{ $j\in\mathbb{N}$}\\ f(-x)& \text{if }~~x  <0.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

where $P_n(x)= -2^{2n+2}(x-n)^2+2^{n+2}(x-n)$. One can check that $f$ is an even and continuous function. since $P_n(n)= P_n(n+\frac{1}{2^n})=0$. Next observe that $f\in L^1(\Bbb R)$ since
\begin{align*}
\int_\mathbb{R} f(x)\,dx= 2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{n/2}\int_{n}^{n+\frac{1}{2^n}} P_n(x) dx 
\\= 2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}-4\cdot 2^{n/2}
\left[ \frac{2^{2n}}{3}(x-n)^3-\frac{2^n}{2}(x-n)^2\right]_{n}^{n+\frac{1}{2^n}}\\
= \frac43\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n/2}}<\infty. 
\end{align*}
Moreover, for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ one has
\begin{align*}
f(n+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}) = 2^{n/2} P_n ( n+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}) = 2^{n/2}\to \infty 
\end{align*}
Therefore $f$ is unbounded.

**Another example**

\begin{align*}
f(x)= \begin{cases}
2^{\frac32(n+1)} x- n2^{\frac32(n+1)}& \text{if} ~~ n\le x\le n+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}} ~~\text{$n\in\mathbb{N}$}\\
-2^{\frac32(n+1)} x= n2^{\frac32(n+1)} +2^{\frac{n+3}{2}}& \text{if} ~~ n+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\le x\le n+\frac{1}{2^n} ~~\text{$n\in\mathbb{N}$}\\
0 &\text{ if}~~~j+\frac{1}{2^j}\le x\le j+1~~\text{$j\in\mathbb{N}$}\\ f(-x)& \text{if }~~x  <0.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
It is easy to check that $f\in L^1(\Bbb R)\cap C(\Bbb R)$
\begin{align*}
&\int_\mathbb{R} f(x)\,dx=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{-\frac{n+1}{2}}<\infty\\
&f(n)= f(n+\frac{1}{2^{n}})=0\qquad f(n+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}) = 2^{\frac{n+1}{2}}\to \infty 
\end{align*}