# Counterexample with continuous unbounded $f$ but $\iint _{\mathbb R^2} |f|^2 dxdy < \infty$ .

Tags: analysis

I want to find a continuous unbounded function $f\colon \mathbb R ^2 \to \mathbb R$ with $\iint _{\mathbb R^2} |f|^2\, dx\,dy < \infty$ .

At first I thought it would be easy, but the continuity makes it harder. And the more I am thinking , the more I am convinced it is not possible. And I cannot prove either that it is not possible. Any idea or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know how to do this when $f$ is a map $\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$?

Comment: @AlexR That's not true.

Comment: @Potato Oh, I see it now myself. Didn't think about summing bumps ;)

Comment: Some idea are given in the 1-dimensional case here, which you can easily adapt to the 2-dimension version: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482934/continuous-unbounded-but-integrable-functions

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2527941/if-f-in-l1-bbb-r-dx-then-prove-that-for-almost-every-x-in-bbb-r-lim-lim

Answer (score 3):

Consider the function $f:[0,+\infty)\to\mathbb R$ whose graph is the polyngonal line with vertices 
\begin{align}
&(0,0),\\
&(1-\tfrac1{2},0),(1,1),(1+\tfrac1{2},0),\\
&(2-\tfrac1{2^2},0),(2,2),(2+\tfrac1{2^2},0),\\
&(3-\tfrac1{2^3},0),(3,3),(3+\tfrac1{2^3},0),\\
\dots
\end{align}
This is unbounded, continuous, and square-integrable.

Now consider $g:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ such that $g(x)=f(||x||)$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Consider points $a_n=(0,n)$, where $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Make $f^2$ in the following way. Take  at $a_n$ a cone of height $n$ and volume $1/2^n$ and $f^2$ is equal to 0 otherwise. Let $f$ be a nonegatitive square root of $f^2$. It is continuous (why?) and the integral is bounded (why?).

Answer (score 1):

If you have an example for $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ you can extend this by
$$f(x,y) := f(x)\phi(y)$$
Where $\phi(y) \in L^2(\mathbb R)$ is a bump (such as the gaussian $\phi(y) = \exp(-y^2)$).
For one dimension, think of a sequence of compactly supported bumps with increasing height but decreasing with. Take a bump function $\psi\in L^2([0,1]) \cap C_0^0([0,1])$ with $\|\psi\|_{L^2} = 1$ and let $f$ be a sum of shifted and scaled copies of $\psi$
$$f = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k \sqrt k\psi(kx-1)$$
Such that $\{a_k\}\in \ell^2(\mathbb N_0)$. Then $f$ satisfies the conditions and
$$\|f\|^2_{L^2} \le \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k^2 \|\psi\|^2_{L^2} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k^2 = \|a_k\|_{\ell^2} < \infty$$
A concrete $a_k$ can be $a_k = \frac1k$ and a concrete $\psi$ can be
$$\psi(x) = \begin{cases} \sqrt{ 4x} & x\in[0,\frac12]\\ \sqrt{1-4x} & x\in(\frac12, 1]\\0&x\notin[0,1]\end{cases}$$